# A vanilla BPSK set up, but constellation disgram is a line

Tags: gnuradio, bpsk, constellation-diagram

I set up a vanilla BPSK modulation in GNU-radio, but the constellation is showing me a line.
[image]

[image]

I am using: `firdes.root.raise_cosine(1.0,samp_rate,samp_rate/sps,excess_bw,11*sps)`

It has been a while since I was last involved with DSP. I know if timing and phase are off then I would expect a line in constellation for BPSK, but since this set up has none of those, why is it giving a line? what am I missing here?

Comment: hey, a remark from the former GNU Radio maintainer: Your version of GNU Radio is end-of-life. Please update to a more modern version of GNU Radio. We fixed **several** bugs in the packet and modulation handling in GNU Radio, so this is really not optional. Also, your version of GNU Radio is so old, it doesn't even work on very modern systems anymore. Developing anything in GNU Radio 3.7 in 2022 really is developing for something to be never used again.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, Marcus. Yes, the latest GNU radio works like a charm :-). Initially, I wanted a quick setup so I didn't border to upgrade (my ubuntu was like 16.xx so the upgrade for me was an entire package from OS to python to GNU radio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constellation diagram will only look like what you're expecting if you view it after matched filtering at 1 sample per symbol - i.e. the constellation plot should be displaying your ideal sampling points of the symbols. In your current setup it looks like you generating bpsk at 4 samples per symbol so the constellation diagram being a line makes sense.

While you could probably manually decimate with a 4x decimating FIR as a quick hack to get something close - usually what you would do is use e.g. the symbol sync (older gnuradio versions it might only be pfb clock sync) that can do matched filtering and symbol timing synchronization simulataneously. For example, this block might use a combination of a polyphase filter bank and a timing error detector to form a control loop such that mis-matches between tx/rx symbol clock & phase can be corrected. Essentially this block will take your 4 SPS signal and perform matched filtering on it and give you an output at 1 SPS that should be the optimal sampling points of your symbols.

I'd suggest taking a look at the gnuradio tutorials as they show this in more detail.

https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/Guided_Tutorial_PSK_Demodulation

Comment: thanks for the answer. I had it figured out (at least the current problem was solved). Yes, I did not down-sample after I up-sampled. Also, the RRC_tap setting must be customized after some digging. The Polyphase filter also messed up the gain, so a multiplier was also added.